# Map pins line up in the Antarctica

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a test map at http://www.itamer.com/wp-content/plugins/sk-openheatmap/test.htm

The JSON data that I'm using is valid and if I copy the coordinates and put them in a normal query the results show the right city. However on my test map using the most basic example possible my pins show up in a line through the ocean and Antarctica.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[35.4798757,-79.1802994]}}
```

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geojson coordinates expect a lng , lat object, whereas other google maps object do expect a google.maps.latLng object. Since you don't say what's your working source, I suggest you check if you are feeding your geoJson the coordjnates in transposed order.

After all, latitude -80 is antarctica, whereas longitude -80 is central USA. That's consistent with your situation, isn't it?

Comment: And I took so much care to ensure they were in the order they came back from the geocode api in! Thank you, literally made a world of difference.